# ASP.NET Cookies are being set with no value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass data from the login controller to the home controller via a cookie.  This seems like it shouldn't be a big deal, but the cookie is being written with no value.  Quite frustrating.

The code I'm using to set the cookie:

```
Customer user = new Customer();
int pass;
pass = MD5Hash(formResult.password);
if (pass == customer.CM_PASSWORD_HASH)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(customer.CM_FULL_NAME, true);
    HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("User");

    userCookie.Values.Add("id", customer.CM_CUSTOMER_ID.ToString());
    userCookie.Values.Add("companyid", customer.CM_COMPANY_ID.ToString());
    userCookie.Values["type"] = "customer";
    userCookie.Values["name"] = customer.CM_FULL_NAME;

    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(userCookie);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This is what I'm trying to use to read the cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("User"))
{
    HttpCookie userCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"];
    switch (userCookie.Values["type"])
    {
        case "customer":
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.BridgeTrakId = Int32.Parse(Response.Cookies.Get("User").Values["id"]);
            customer.CompanyId = Int32.Parse(Response.Cookies.Get("User").Values["companyid"]);
            customer.Name = Response.Cookies.Get("User").Values["name"];
            model.User = customer;
            model.Equipment = DataAccess.EquipmentRepository.GetEquipment(customer.BridgeTrakId);
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The cookie gets created, and when I view it in the Chrome tools, the name is there, but the value is empty.  When I view the userCookie in visual studio, it shows that it has a value.

Can anyone explain to me where I am losing the value, and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve **id, companyid and name** same as you did for **type**.

```
HttpCookie userCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"];
switch (userCookie.Values["type"])
{
    case "customer":
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.BridgeTrakId = Int32.Parse(userCookie.Values["id"]);
        customer.CompanyId = Int32.Parse(userCookie.Values["companyid"]);
        customer.Name = userCookie.Values["name"];
        ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

### Another Method

```
Request.Cookies["User"]["type"]
Request.Cookies["User"]["id"]
Request.Cookies["User"]["companyid"]
Request.Cookies["User"]["name"]
```

**Note:** I do not know the reason behind passing data. Ideally, you do not want to cookie just to pass data between controller. Instead, you want to use **QueryString** or **SessionState**.

Comment: I'm typically a desktop developer, just getting into my first MVC project, so there is much in the way of a learning curve.  I like your answer better than mine, though.  Thanks!  I'll look into SessionState.  QueryString is also URL encoding, right?

Comment: I see. In ASP.Net, we don't normally use cookie to pass data between pages. ***FYI***: you can also use [TempData](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html) in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: I think that the most difficult thing for me, in terms of switching from desktop development to web or client/server development is keeping state persistence straight.  What happens to x, y, or z variable as the session is created and destroyed on each page load, and how to keep persistent data from "contaminating" sessions, if that is even possible.

Comment: Although they are persist the data, each has own purpose. ***What happens to x, y, or z variable as the session is created and destroyed on each page load*** using **Session** is not a good practice for such scenario. **QueryString** or **TempData** might be a good choice for passing data between two pages. If we want to persist data more than two pages, we use **SessionState**. However, if you want to persist data even browser is closed, we use **Cookie**. Again, each has pro and con.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the cookie like so.

```
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie");
        cookie.Value = "Hello Cookie! CreatedOn: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach.  Is that just to test if the cookie is actually getting set?  I managed to resolve the issue, but I'm not sure why what I did works when what I was doing doesn't....